# Fitting a curve between 2 poses (position and orientation) when the length of the curve is known

Tags: geometry, linear-transformations, regression, bezier-curve, hermite-polynomials

I have two visual aruco markers on a flexible line and a camera. I can calculate the pose (position and orientation) of each marker. I have measured the distance between the markers when the line is straight. I want to approximate the line between the markers based on the marker poses and the length of the line.

My current approach is to create a hermite curve from 2 poses. However the magnitudes of the tangents of the start and end points need to be found experimentally to best fit my real line. I want to use the length of the line to calculate the hermite curve tangent magnitudes and therefore have a better approximation of my line. Is this possible? I am unsure how I can combine the arc length equation and the hermite curve equation.

[hermite curve equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yo5PP.png)

[arc length equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HZSu.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It might surprise you to learn that most mathematicians do not know what an "aruco marker" is, and how its poses relate to the line. I am guessing they determine the direction of the tangent to the line, but not its magnitude. So while they completely determine the two $\bf p$ vectors, the $\bf m$ vectors only have direction determined, not magnitudes, so you still have two free parameters that need specified to define the curve. You need two more independent equations to define them. However, "arclength $= L$" is only one equation. You are still one equation short.

Comment: A common approach to handling this is to just make an arbitrary assumption that the magnitude of the tangents at the two markers is the same. If you think of the curve as a "roadway" that someone is travelling down with the curve giving their position at time $t$, then this require means they must pass the second marker at the same speed as they passed the first - though they may speed up and slow down inbetween. With this requirement and your constant arclength requirement, you will have enough information to find the curve - but it may be a poor approximation of your line.